# Read Parquet file from Azure blob with out downloading it locally c# .net

Tags: c#, azure, blob, parquet

We have a parquet formatfile (500 mb) which is located in Azure blob.How to read the file directly from blob and save in memory of c# ,say eg:Datatable.

I am able to read parquet file which is physically located in folder using the below code.

```
public void ReadParqueFile()
    {
         using (Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("D:/../userdata1.parquet"))     
        {
            using (var parquetReader = new ParquetReader(fileStream))
            {
                DataField[] dataFields = parquetReader.Schema.GetDataFields();

                for (int i = 0; i < parquetReader.RowGroupCount; i++)
                {

                    using (ParquetRowGroupReader groupReader = parquetReader.OpenRowGroupReader(i))
                    {
                        DataColumn[] columns = dataFields.Select(groupReader.ReadColumn).ToArray();

                        DataColumn firstColumn = columns[0];

                        Array data = firstColumn.Data;
                        //int[] ids = (int[])data;
                    }
                }
           }
        }

    }
}
```

(I am able to read csv file directly from blob using sourcestream).Please kindly suggest a fastest method to read the parquet file directly from blob

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, the solution to directly read the parquet file from blob is first to generate the blob url with sas token and then to get the stream of `HttpClient` from the url with sas and finally to read the http response stream via `ParquetReader`.

First, please refer to the sample code below of the section [`Create a service SAS for a blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-service-sas-create-dotnet) of the offical document `Create a service SAS for a container or blob with .NET` using Azure Blob Storage SDK for .NET Core.

```
private static string GetBlobSasUri(CloudBlobContainer container, string blobName, string policyName = null)
{
    string sasBlobToken;

    // Get a reference to a blob within the container.
    // Note that the blob may not exist yet, but a SAS can still be created for it.
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

    if (policyName == null)
    {
        // Create a new access policy and define its constraints.
        // Note that the SharedAccessBlobPolicy class is used both to define the parameters of an ad hoc SAS, and
        // to construct a shared access policy that is saved to the container's shared access policies.
        SharedAccessBlobPolicy adHocSAS = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            // When the start time for the SAS is omitted, the start time is assumed to be the time when the storage service receives the request.
            // Omitting the start time for a SAS that is effective immediately helps to avoid clock skew.
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Create
        };

        // Generate the shared access signature on the blob, setting the constraints directly on the signature.
        sasBlobToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(adHocSAS);

        Console.WriteLine("SAS for blob (ad hoc): {0}", sasBlobToken);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    else
    {
        // Generate the shared access signature on the blob. In this case, all of the constraints for the
        // shared access signature are specified on the container's stored access policy.
        sasBlobToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(null, policyName);

        Console.WriteLine("SAS for blob (stored access policy): {0}", sasBlobToken);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    // Return the URI string for the container, including the SAS token.
    return blob.Uri + sasBlobToken;
}
```

Then to get the http response stream of `HttpClient` from the url with sas token .

```
var blobUrlWithSAS = GetBlobSasUri(container, blobName);
var client = new HttpClient();
var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(blobUrlWithSAS);
```

Finally to read it via `ParquetReader`, the code comes from [`Reading Data`](https://github.com/aloneguid/parquet-dotnet/blob/develop/doc/reading.md) of GitHub repo [`aloneguid/parquet-dotnet`](https://github.com/aloneguid/parquet-dotnet).

```
var options = new ParquetOptions { TreatByteArrayAsString = true };
var reader = new ParquetReader(stream, options);
```

Comment: Thanks Peter.I have tried  var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(blobUrl); this  but It getting time out issue..I was able to read small csv file using this method directly from blob with out locally downloading ..Actuallty I have to read either 1.7 GB csv file or corresponding parquet file of around 500 mb directly from blob

Comment: Hi, am getting the below error when using the same logic. However, am able to print the file using streamreader. Any idea. Thanks

"not a Parquet file(head is '')"

Comment: @Subba I'm having the same error. Did you resolve it?

Comment: We get the same error  - anyone found a working version?

Comment: The Parquet.Net documentation mentions that files cannot be read from a network stream.  See https://github.com/aloneguid/parquet-dotnet#reading-files