# Read and Query Parquet files from Azure Data Lake Using Azure Function without downloading locally C#

Tags: c#, azure, parquet, azure-data-lake

We have a requirement to read all the parquet files available in Azure Data Lake and dump in SQL database. But instead due to some business rules & limit my data, I want to filter the dataset without actually downloading the files to my local. Is there any such nuget package or library available for dot net with any sample code? Any suggestions?

Comment: What backend infrastructure do you have setup against the lake for processing that data?  i.e. Spark?  DataBricks?  Synapse SQL Dedicated or Serverless?!?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a successful workaround available in java

```
 StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(accountName, accountKey);
 CloudStorageAccount connection = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);
 CloudBlobClient blobClient = connection.createCloudBlobClient();
 CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference(containerName);

 CloudBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(fileName);

 Configuration config = new Configuration();
 config.set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem");
 config.set("fs.azure.sas.<containerName>.<accountName>.blob.core.windows.net", token);
 URI uri = new URI("wasbs://<containerName>@<accountName>.blob.core.windows.net/" + blob.getName());
 InputFile file = HadoopInputFile.fromPath(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(uri),
                config);
 ParquetReader<GenericRecord> reader = AvroParquetReader.<GenericRecord> builder(file).build();

 GenericRecord record;
 while ((record = reader.read()) != null) {
     System.out.println(record);
 }
 reader.close();
```

Here is one of the work around in C# that you can try

```
var connectionString = String.Format("<YOUR CONNECTION STRING>");

var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("<YOUR CONTAINER NAME>");

SharedAccessBlobPolicy sasConstraints = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
sasConstraints.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(2);
sasConstraints.Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.List;

CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("<YOUR PARQUET FILE>");
var blobUrlWithSAS = blob.Uri + blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints);

var client = new HttpClient();
var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(blobUrlWithSAS);

ParquetReader parquetReader = new ParquetReader();

var options = new ParquetOptions {
    TreatByteArrayAsString = true
};
var reader = new ParquetReader(stream, options);
```

**REFERENCES:**

- [Read Parquet file from Azure blob with out downloading it locally c# .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59981589/read-parquet-file-from-azure-blob-with-out-downloading-it-locally-c-sharp-net)
- [Read parquet data from Azure Blob container without downloading it locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56026462/read-parquet-data-from-azure-blob-container-without-downloading-it-locally)
- [parquet-dotnet/ParquetReader.cs at master · aloneguid/parquet-dotnet](https://github.com/aloneguid/parquet-dotnet/blob/master/src/Parquet/ParquetReader.cs)

Comment: I followed the above java answer, but I am stuck with file not found exception while file is present.  Here is my code present: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71592646/azure-java-file-not-found-exception-when-trying-to-access-file-from-azure Can you take a look what is wrong in it?